# Can mathematica numerically solve this system of coupled integro differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, fluid-dynamics

Here's my system:
[image: Chemical diffusing across the square region is absorbed by the mobile, circular sink, which updates its position in response to the distribution of chemical around its circumference]

R(x,y,t) is the concentration of a chemical that's diffusing across the box. The disk is a mobile sink for the chemical, which absorbs it in proportion to its concentration. The chemical dynamics are therefore described by the 2D diffusion equation with a sink term.

The coordinates of the disk's centre (x_c(t),y_c(t)) are updated in the following way. At each moment, the `centre of mass' (x_cr(t),y_cr(t)) of the chemical concentration around the disk's circumference is calculated and a force is applied along the vector from (x_c(t),y_c(t)) to (x_cr(t),y_cr(t)). A drag force also acts in the opposite direction. That is, the disk 'swims' up the local chemical concentration gradient. The sink position dynamics are thus described by Newton's 2nd law.

R(x,y,t) and (x_c(t),y_c(t)) are coupled. I want to solve numerically for R, x_c and y_c.

I'm trying this with NDSolve:

```
NDSolve[{Derivative[0, 0, 1][R][x, y, t] == 
(-R[x, y, t])*UnitStep[1 + x - xc[t], 1 - x + xc[t], 
   y + Sqrt[(1 + x - xc[t])*(1 - x + xc[t])] - yc[t], 
   -y + Sqrt[(1 + x - xc[t])*(1 - x + xc[t])] + yc[t]] + 
 Derivative[0, 2, 0][R][x, y, t] + Derivative[2, 0, 0][R][
  x, y, t], Derivative[2][xc][t] == 
Integrate[R[Cos[\[Phi]] + xc[t], Sin[\[Phi]] + yc[t], t]*
    (Cos[\[Phi]] + xc[t]), {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}]/
  Integrate[R[Cos[\[Phi]] + xc[t], Sin[\[Phi]] + yc[t], t], 
   {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}] - xc[t] - Derivative[1][xc][t], Derivative[2][yc][t] == 
Integrate[R[Cos[\[Phi]] + xc[t], Sin[\[Phi]] + yc[t], t]*
    (Sin[\[Phi]] + yc[t]), {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}]/
  Integrate[R[Cos[\[Phi]] + xc[t], Sin[\[Phi]] + yc[t], t], 
   {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}] - yc[t] - Derivative[1][yc][t], R[x, y, 0] == 0, R[-5, y, t] == Sin[10*t], R[5, y, t] == 1, R[x, -5, t] == 1, R[x, 5, t] == 1, xc[0] == 0, yc[0] == 0, Derivative[1][xc][0] == 0, Derivative[1][yc][0] == 0}, {R, xc, yc}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

The integrals (which calculate the 'centre of mass' of the chemical) are only over the dummy variable `\[Phi]`.

I get the error 'NDSolve: The arguments should be ordered consistently'.

Here's an image of the system in Mathematica, where it's easier to see what's going on:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or am I asking too much of NDSolve? Can anyone think of a way to solve this system with Mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: Are some boundary conditions on the sink border or it is as in your code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, the BCs are only at the box boundaries. Diffusion continues through the interior of the sink. Whereas outside the sink, the diffusion is conservative, at every point inside it the chemical is lost in proportion to its concentration. As you can see, there's a periodic 'driving' boundary condition at (-5, y) but this is arbitrary.

Comment: In your code boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. Why not to put `R[x, y, 0] == 1, R[-5, y, t] == Cos[10*t]`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, thanks for pointing that out! I updated it as suggested and I'm afraid I still get the same error message....